# All imports are undefined for one module during Jest test run

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

Strange bug with Jest, create-react-app, and typescript.

Tonight Jest started failing to import my "./ProcessStore" module correctly. This module is a transitive dependency of something that my tests import.

The error I see is that the thing I import is undefined.

When I do `import * as what from "./ProcessStore"` and log(what), it prints all of the exports, but the values are undefined. Like `{default: undefined, ResourceChange: undefined}` two classes that are exported. It should be `{default: <a class>, ResourceChange: <a class>}`.

It's just that one file. Every other file works.

When I use npm start, it works --- this is a Jest only problem.

Also if I rename the broken file to say `./ProcessStore2`, it also works.

I tried `./node_modules/jest --clearCache`, which didn't help.

In case it's relevant, I'm using craco normally. Switching back to react-scripts temporarily didn't help.

I'm using react-scripts 4.0.3 (latest version).

What is going on? How do I fix this silly problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was caused by a circular dependency in my project.

The circular dependency was causing Jest to return an empty module. I believe the 2nd time a module is entered, it will have undefined contents.

In my case the chain was `ProcessStore.ts -> stores.ts -> ProcessStore.ts`. So by the time `stores.ts` loads `ProcessStore.ts`, the process store has already been loaded, so everything is undefined.

Comment: So how did you fix it? Did you remove circular dependency? I'm asking because I have exactly the same issue, but removing circular dependency will be a huge work...

Comment: @drazewski yes unfortunately I did fix the circular dep. There may be a different fix, im not aware of any though.

Comment: in my case, i just mocked the file which had the circular dependency in that particular test

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this when I was importing in one file like this

```
import { myHook } from 'services/hooks/myHook'
```

and in another file

```
import { myHook } from 'services/hooks'
```

There was an index file

```
// src/services/hooks/index.ts
export * from './myHook.ts'
```

Converting them all to use the index path fixed it.  I don't think I had a circular dependency anywhere, I never was able to truly understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this issue, due to a circular dependency.

In order to confirm the nature of the bug, I `console.log` the missing import and executed my test. I could see that the import was in fact `undefined` when it shouldn't have been.

I ran this command to find circular dependencies at package/project level:

```
npx madge --circular --extensions ts,tsx .
```

This only gave me a clue as to what was going on, however.

I then used the `debugger` at the point where my circular dependency was occurring. Using Chrome DevTools, I inspected the call stack, and found how each import was being imported. This revealed the circular dependency very clearly. For me, this was the most important part of untangling the circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case when I had no circular dependencies, but imports still were `undefined` in a lib in a small monorepo. It sounds weird, but using shorter filenames resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a combination of the IDE being unable to map variable names, and I was passing the wrong argument.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7960564407442-When-debugging-with-jest-values-are-displayed-as-undefined-while-they-have-values